# Why doesn't RandomChoice work here?

Tags: random

I was using `RandomChoice` to run a simulation to test the probability that picking 4 marbles out of a bag containing 3 red and 7 blue marbles you get 2 red and 2 blue. Here's the code:

```
ls = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0};

ngood = 0; ntot = 1000000;
Do[
  If[Plus @@ RandomChoice[ls, {4}] == 2, ngood++],
  {ntot}];
ngood/ntot // N
```

> `0.26494`

The problem is that probability can be easily computed as $0.3$. Using a code that avoids `RandomChoice` gives the correct answer:

```
ngood = 0; ntot = 1000000;
Do[
  n = {};
  While[Length[n] < 4, 
    n = Union[n, {RandomInteger[{1, 10}]}]];
    If[Plus @@ ls[[n]] == 2, ngood++],
  {ntot}];
ngood/ntot // N
```

> `0.29985`

Does the first code example actually demonstrate a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Using `Union` in the second case, you are excluding multiple identical draws - `RandomChoice` does not do that in the first snippet, so your code samples are not equivalent. If you substitute `n = Append[n, RandomInteger[{1, 10}]]` in the second sample, the results seem similar enough.

Comment: Consider `RandomSample` instead.

Comment: You are right: I should have used `RandomSample`. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RandomChoice` is not the correct function for your problem. It models the situation where you return a marble to the bag after you remove it and before you make the next choice.

For the situation where a marble is not returned to the bag after it is removed, use `RandomSample`.

```
marbles = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0};
Module[{ngood = 0, ntot = 1000000}, 
  Do[If[Total[RandomSample[marbles, 4]] == 2, ngood++], {ntot}]; 
  ngood/ntot // N]
```

> `0.300757`

We should all keep in mind

> $\qquad$RandomSample  = sampling *without* replacement
>   $\qquad$RandomChoice$\ \ $= sampling *with* replacement

Comment: Perhaps it would be useful to slightly rephrase the question ("why are xxx not equivalent)  and reopen?

Comment: @YvesKlett. That would seem to require a major rewrite of the question. Is there precedent for that? And, presuming there is, are you proposing to undertake making the rewrite? If you do, I'll vote to reopen.

Comment: hrmm... and then it might be closed anyway because "easily found in the documentation"... not completely decided.

Comment: @YvesKlett. I changed the title and voted to reopen. Let's see what happens. Your vote to reopen would encourage others.

Comment: super, done. Let's see how that works out.